# Arrow key navigation in new tag box is counterintuitive

Tags: bug, tags, tag-autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make up/down go up and down instead of left and right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101498/make-up-down-go-up-and-down-instead-of-left-and-right)

When there are enough suggested tags for there two be two rows in the tag box...

[image: ...like this...]

...hitting the <kbd>down</kbd> arrow key moves the selection one tag to the right, instead of one tag down. I find this confusing.

Comment: It makes sense. They hook onto one axis. Remember DOS (or maybe you are too young).

Comment: I promise I tried to search for duplicates before posting. Just not hard enough, apparently.